# Swift: How to zip multiple NSData objects for further transfer (Airdrop, Email, Dropbox...)

Tags: ios, swift, zip, realm, nsdata

In my iOS Swift application I have images stored as NSData in a Realm database. Now I want to combine these images (or a subset query of them) into a single ZIP file and make it available for further transfer via Airdrop, Email and so on.

I am fine with how to transfer and how to get them out of the database but I have no clue how to create a single ZIP file out of a bunch of NSData objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing some keywords in Google for the search, I found 2 interesting looking Libs/Frameworks I now will start investigating in.

[ZIP from Marmelroy](https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip)

and

[ZipArchive](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive)

Both can be found on GitHub. I have no big experiences with both of them at the moment. But `ZipArchive`seems to have options for `NSData`Support as this is already stated in the Readme

`Zip-up NSData instances. (with a filename)`

So this might be an indicator for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply serialize and archive your images instead before AirDrop sharing. See [AirDropSample](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/sc2273/Introduction/Intro.html).